# Deleting from array using unset creates values

Tags: php

```
$array = [ 0, 5, 7 ];
```

For this array, I want to `unset` without it assigning a value.

When I `unset($array[5])` it will return

```
{
    "0" => 0,
    "1" => 5,
    "2" => 7
}
```

But my actual goal is to make it return like

`[ 0, 7 ]`

That way when I use `json_encode` it will just show up as

```
[ 
    0,
    7
]
```

Is this possible at all? I googled and everyone just mentions indexing, but I am looking at just removing this number from the array. Not have it reindex or change the formatting of it to have a value.

Comment: Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php. That will give your the key then use that in the `[]`. Something like `unset($array[array_search(5, $array)])` presuming the values are unique.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter within the brackets on `$array[]` is actually the numerical index or associative index (arrays in PHP are maps).

In your case, you want to do:

```
unset($arr[1]);
```

Comment: Even when using this, it still creates the value aspect of it. So when I use `json_encode` it shows values.

Comment: Actually that's interesting when using `print_r` it shows the values like so. But why does it not do that with `json_encode` until I unset something from it.

Comment: I just saw that your array at the start of your post differs from the second one. What is the real situation you are having?

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. I just have a var set to `[0,5,7]` and when you use `json_encode` it only shows `[0,5,7]` but when you unset from that array and then json_encode does its thing again. It returns `[ "0" => 0, "7" => 7 ]`

Comment: `json_encode` is not returning an array but a string. I guess you are mixing up some things in your not shared code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = [0,5,7];
array_splice($a, 1, 1); // remove from position 1 - remove 1 entry

echo json_encode($a);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/S0uZS).

#### output

```
[0,7]
```

#### references

- [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

#### additional informaion

Unset wont work as is, since it preserves the initial keys.

A solution with unset is to ignore the keys by using [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$a = [0,5,7];

unset($a[1]);
$a = array_values($a);

echo json_encode($a);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/798Bu).

Same output as above.

Comment: *"Unset wont work as is, since it preserves the initial keys."* ...and to clarify why, it's because JSON will only treat 0-base, sequential indexes as an array, and will treat non-sequential or N-base arrays like associative arrays, ie. they become JSON objects with the index key included.

Comment: consecutively is the word you are looking for :P

Comment: I'll be damned, true that. *"Sequential = succeeding or following in order; consecutive = following, in succession, without interruption"*. Ie. 1, 2, 4 is sequential non-consecutive. PHP manual also uses "sequential", those an-alphabetic basterds.  *"Example #4 Sequential versus non-sequential array example*" ~ [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Should file a bug report, actually consequentially misleading terminology, this!